# WP_query only displays one of my custom post type entries

Tags: wp-query, shortcode

I create a custom post type and wrote a shortcode to display the posts on the front end of my website, but the code only displays one (1) post, and the most recent one. See front-end page here -> https://www.800goldlaw.com/careers. The CPT is the "jobs board".

Here is my code. Any advice for cleaning this code up and making sure all of my posts display on the front end? Thank you!

```
function locg_view_jobs($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
                array( //default values
                'post_type' => 'locg_jobs',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                ), 
                $atts, 'locgviewjobs' );

    global $post;

    $posts = new WP_query($atts);
    $output = '';
    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'job_cat'); foreach ($terms as $term) { $job_cat_links[]=$term->name; }
    $job_cat_go = join(",", $job_cat_links);

        if ($posts->have_posts())
            while ($posts->have_posts()):
                $posts->the_post();
                $out = '<div class="job_post"><h4><a href=" ' . get_the_permalink() . '" title="Apply Now" />' . get_the_title() . '</a></h4>
                        <div class="jobs_meta">
                        <span class="meta">Posted Date:</span> ' . get_the_date() . '</span> | <span class="meta">Open Until:</span> ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'expiredate', true) . ' | <span class="meta">Department:</span> ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Department', true) . ' </div>
                        <p>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>
                        <a class="red_link" target="_blank" href=" ' . get_the_permalink() . '" /><button class="red" style="margin-right: 10px;"/>Learn More</button></a>
                        <a class="red_link" target="_blank" href="http://gld.la/2GciVF4" /><button class="red"/>Apply Now</button></a>
                        </div>';

    endwhile;
    else return( 'Sorry, there are no jobs available at this time. Check back often! In the meantime, you can fill out a blank application for us to hold on file. <a href="http://gld.la/2GciVF4" target="_blank" />Click here</a>.' );
    wp_reset_query();
    return html_entity_decode($out);
}
add_shortcode( 'locgviewjobs', 'locg_view_jobs');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `'posts_per_page' => -1,` to your default atts.  This will make the query return all of the posts instead of limiting it.  Also you're overriding `$out` each loop instead of adding to it.  Change `$out = '<div class` to `$out .= '<div class`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately, made no difference.

Comment: found it.  you're overriding your output each time you loop through a post instead of adding to it.  I'll add the fix to my answer.

Comment: Yup, your second fix did the trick. What's the significance of that period there? Just curious...

Comment: `.=` adds to the existing variable, `=` sets the variable to a new value.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function locg_view_jobs($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
                array( //default values
                'post_type' => 'locg_jobs',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                ), 
                $atts, 'locgviewjobs' );

    global $post;

    $posts = new WP_query($atts);
    $out = '';

    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'job_cat');

    foreach ($terms as $term) { 
         $job_cat_links[]=$term->name;
    }

    $job_cat_go = join(",", $job_cat_links);

        if ($posts->have_posts())
            while ($posts->have_posts()):
                $posts->the_post();
                $out .= '<div class="job_post"><h4><a href=" ' . get_the_permalink() . '" title="Apply Now" />' . get_the_title() . '</a></h4>
                        <div class="jobs_meta">
                        <span class="meta">Posted Date:</span> ' . get_the_date() . '</span> | <span class="meta">Open Until:</span> ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'expiredate', true) . ' | <span class="meta">Department:</span> ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Department', true) . ' </div>
                        <p>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>
                        <a class="red_link" target="_blank" href=" ' . get_the_permalink() . '" /><button class="red" style="margin-right: 10px;"/>Learn More</button></a>
                        <a class="red_link" target="_blank" href="http://gld.la/2GciVF4" /><button class="red"/>Apply Now</button></a>
                        </div>';

    endwhile;
    else return( 'Sorry, there are no jobs available at this time. Check back often! In the meantime, you can fill out a blank application for us to hold on file. <a href="http://gld.la/2GciVF4" target="_blank" />Click here</a>.' );
    wp_reset_query();
    return html_entity_decode($out);
}
add_shortcode( 'locgviewjobs', 'locg_view_jobs');
```

Comment: Thank you - the solution above yours worked for me!

Comment: Glad to know that it worked. Please mark this as **Accepted Answer** to help other searching for similar problem. Thanks